# Keep pixel aspect with different resolution in xna game

Tags: xna, pixel

I'm currently developping an old-school game with XNA 4.
My graphics assets are based on 568x320 resolution (16/9 ration), I want to change my window resolution (1136x640 for example) and my graphics are scaled without stretching, that they keep pixel aspect.

How can I reach this ?

Comment: you could draw the image to a texture and afterwards, draw that texture to the screen and the texture will scale accordingly.

Comment: That depends on the type of the game. Maybe you have a background that can be tiled. If not, then you probably have to live with black bars when changing aspect ratio. However, changing the resolution does only make sense, if your assets have a sufficient resolution. The Prerendering approach is similar. It will probably even worsen graphics quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Gosh !!!! I've got it ! Just give SamplerState.PointClamp at your spriteBatch.Begin methods to keep that cool pixel visuel effet <3

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,
                    BlendState.AlphaBlend, 
                    SamplerState.PointClamp,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    cam.getTransformation(this.GraphicsDevice));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `RenderTarget`to achieve your goal. It sounds like you don't want to have to render accordingly to every possible screen size, so if your graphics aren't dependant on other graphical features like a mouse, then I would use a `RenderTarget` and draw all the pixel data to that and afterwards draw it to the actual screen allowing the screen to stretch it.

This technique can be used in other ways too. I use it to draw objects in my game, so I can easily change the rotation and location without having to calculate every sprite for the object.

Example:

```
void PreDraw() 
    // You need your graphics device to render to
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = Settings.GlobalGraphicsDevice;
    // You need a spritebatch to begin/end a draw call
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch = Settings.GlobalSpriteBatch;
    // Tell the graphics device where to draw too
    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
    // Clear the buffer with transparent so the image is transparent
    graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    flameAnimation.Draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.Draw(gunTextureToDraw, new Vector2(100, 0), Color.White);

    if (!base.CurrentPowerUpLevel.Equals(PowerUpLevels.None)) {
        powerUpAnimation.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    // DRAWS THE IMAGE TO THE RENDERTARGET
    spriteBatch.Draw(shipSpriteSheet, new Rectangle(105,0, (int)Size.X, (int)Size.Y), shipRectangleToDraw, Color.White);


    spriteBatch.End();
    // Let the graphics device know you are done and return to drawing according to its dimensions
    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    // utilize your render target
    finishedShip = renderTarget;
}
```

Remember, in your case, you would initialize your `RenderTarget` with dimensions of 568x320 and draw according to that and not worry about any other possible sizes. Once you give the `RenderTarget` to the spritebatch to draw to the screen, it will "stretch" the image for you!

EDIT:

Sorry, I skimmed through the question and missed that you don't want to "stretch" your result. This could be achieved by drawing the final `RenderTarget` to your specified dimensions according to the graphics device.

Comment: My bad, i've miss explain my problem. Let's try again : All graphics are pixel art (in resolution 568x320, not matter, it could have been another one). But this resolution is too small to play, so the player can switch resolution to a "zoomed" one. If i use Matrix transformation, or renderTarget my graphics are blurred; in case of 2x zoom (in other word, 1136x640) all pixels of assets are duplicated a second time on each axe, to preserve the pixel art aspect (take a look on hydorah to well understand (freeware)).

Comment: Hmm, Really, the only practical solution I see then for that would be to have larger sprites...

Comment: Anyway, i didn't know what is renderTarget, so i do now. Thanks